# Meaning of "no mechanical delay required" in packer description (oil drilling)

Tags: drilling

[This description](http://www.reactivetools.com/datasheets/reflex_lite.pdf) of the Reflex Lite packer by Reactive states the following among its advantages:

"No mechanical delay required"

What could that mean? The packer has no built-in system of delayed activation or delayed swelling control? Or "there is no need for complex procedures when installing the packer"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just got a reply from the company:

> Some of our competitors use an applied outer layer of material to delay their swell curves (mechanical delay). At Reactive, we select the correct polymer for the well, so no fabricated delay system is required.

Voila.